# Is the following proof okay for "Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers with $b>0$. Prove $|a|<b$ if and only if $-b<a<b$"?

Tags: inequality

Proof: Given $b>0$ and $|a|<b$.
If $a>0$, $|a|<b \implies a < b$
If $a<0$, $|a|<b \implies -a<b \implies a>-b$
Therefore, $-b < a < b$ is proved.
If it's correct, is there any more elegant way to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: Third line should be "if $a<0$"

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch sorry, typo. Edited.

Comment: Otherwise it looks fine to me, however, note that you only prove one direction, while the title states "if and only if" 

Comment: Oops, I forgot! Also is there more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think so (if you start from first principles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not explicitly obtained "$-b < a$" in your first case and you have not explicitly obtained $a < b$ in your second case.  Both omissions are easy to fix.  For instance, in the first case $- b< 0 < a$.

You have not handled the case $a = 0$.

Also, you only have half of the proof.  You are asked to show a biimplication, so you should have another paragraph that assumes "$-b < a < b$" and obtains $|a| < b$.

Since $|a|$ is defined piecewise, you should proceed by breaking your argument into the same pieces.  There may be a "more elegant" way to proceed, but it is worthwhile to work parallel to the definitions first.

Comment: These are helpful notes. But isn't the first case and second case combined enough to prove $-b \lt a \lt b$ ? Do I also need to show them in each cases also?

Comment: @alu : The first and second cases have incompatible $a$s -- one is positive and the other is negative.  You would have to explain their relationship in order to use both together.  Whereas the inequalities I mention are automatic as a result of the assumed signs of these two $a$s.

Comment: How to prove it from the other direction, starting with -b<a<b and proving |a|<b?

Comment: @alu : Same way.  If $a \geq 0$, $|a| = a < b$.  And you handle the other case...

Comment: Thanks. So the other case is: If $a \lt 0, |-a| = a \lt b$. Therefore, $|a| \lt b$ is proved. Is this enough?

Comment: @alu : If $a < 0$, $|-a| = -a$...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more interesting way to say it.  Since $|a| < b$, the distance from $a$ to $0$ is less than $b$.  Therefore $-b < a < b$.

This logic also reverses.